# Extract values from string in swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I have a string as shown below and i am trying to separate each part (,) into an array.

```
let stringArr = remainderString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
```

> 0lY6P5Ur90TAQnnnI6wtnb,#29,Projekt-FZK-Haus,Projekt FZK-House create
>   by KHH Forschuungszentrum Karlsruhe,$,$,$,(#67,#229,#275),#42

**Results**

```
["0lY6P5Ur90TAQnnnI6wtnb", "#29", "Projekt-FZK-Haus", "Projekt FZK-House create by KHH Forschuungszentrum Karlsruhe", "$", "$", "$", "(#67", "#229", "#275)", "#42"]
```

If you notice, the part **(#67,#229,#275)** were separated into "(#67", "#229", "#275)"

I want to insert those values inside the (braces) into an another array. So my question is, how can I locate the opening **(** and then the closing **)** ?

Comment: one question, you want to get all (#67,#229,#275) as one text, or you want only to know when open an closing your parenthesis?

Comment: You could use a [`let regex = "\\([^()]*\\)|[^,]+"`](https://regex101.com/r/fG8wZ6/1) regex to match the substrings separately.

Comment: @ReinierMelian I am trying to match an opening brace with a closing brace.  If i get it as one text, then that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another example. Using UTF-16 based index and range properly, so works with Strings including non-BMP characters.

```
let str = "0lY6P5Ur90TAQnnnI6wtnb,#29,Projekt-FZK-Haus,Projekt FZK-House create by KHH Forschuungszentrum Karlsruhe,$,$,$,(#67,#229,#275),#42"
let pattern = "(\\([^\\)]*\\)|[^\\(,][^,]*)(?:,|$)"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regex.matchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count))
let stringArr = matches.map{match->String in
    let matchingRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
    let matchingString = (str as NSString).substringWithRange(matchingRange) as String
    return matchingString
}
print(stringArr) //->["0lY6P5Ur90TAQnnnI6wtnb", "#29", "Projekt-FZK-Haus", "Projekt FZK-House create by KHH Forschuungszentrum Karlsruhe", "$", "$", "$", "(#67,#229,#275)", "#42"]
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Subscripting a String with NSRange. Make dealing with ObjC-classes easier
extension String {
    subscript(range: NSRange) -> String {
        let startIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location)
        let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(range.length)

        return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
    }
}

let str = "0lY6P5Ur90TAQnnnI6wtnb,#29,Projekt-FZK-Haus,Projekt FZK-House create by KHH Forschuungszentrum Karlsruhe,$,$,$,(#67,#229,#275),#42"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\((#[^\\)]+)\\)", options: [])

if let match = regex.firstMatchInString(str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count)) {
    let substr = str[match.rangeAtIndex(1)]
    let components = substr.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

    print(components)
}
```

Comment: To work with ranges based on NSString's nature, you cannot use `characters` based index. NSString uses UTF-16 based index, so your code needs to be modified to use `utf16`-based index and range.

Comment: @Code Different thanks a lot. I did and it seems to work.